# Detecting multiple checked checkboxes

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Without using JavaScript, I want something to happen only when two checkboxes are checked. So something like

```css
#one:checked && #two:checked ~ p {
    color: red;
}
```

for

```
<input id="one" type="checkbox" name="check"><label for="one">One</label>
<input id="two" type="checkbox" name="check"><label for="two">Two</label>
<p>Thing</p>
```

which obviously doesn't work. Is there a way to detect both checkboxes without using JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Select the second checkbox if the first one is checked, and then from there select the `p` element:

```css
#one:checked ~ #two:checked ~ p {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<input id="one" type="checkbox" name="check"><label for="one">One</label>
<input id="two" type="checkbox" name="check"><label for="two">Two</label>
<p>Thing</p>
```

Of course you could also generalize the selectors if you don't know the order in advance:

```css
input:checked ~ input:checked ~ p {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<input id="one" type="checkbox" name="check"><label for="one">One</label>
<input id="two" type="checkbox" name="check"><label for="two">Two</label>
<p>Thing</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but what you need is:

```css
#one:checked ~ #two:checked ~ p {
    color: red;
}
```